# DirectorySearcher doesn't find locked users

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have the following problem. In my domain there are locked users.
I am not able to query the locked user with the following code.

```
string ls_userfilter = "(SAMAccountName=" + myconfig.UserID + ")";

var ld_directory = new DirectoryEntry(myconfig.LDAPPath, null, null, 
    AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer | AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

SearchResultCollection user;

try
{
    var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(ld_directory);
    searcher.Filter = ls_userfilter;
    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    user = searcher.FindAll();
}
```

Via PowerShell and `PrincipalContext` I am able to get the user.
I am not able to use `PrincipalContext` because of the authentication needed.

Any pointers are helpful.

I tried using `GroupPrincipal`. This is not feasible because of the Server configuration. As I understand it, the server is on LDAPS.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. It should find the user as long as the user's `sAMAccountName` matches `myconfig.UserID`. It doesn't matter if the account is locked or not. Can you show the code you used with `PrincipalContext`? There may be some difference.

Comment: The real problem here is corss-domain. I need to find users in different domains.

Comment: If all the domains you need to search are in the same forest, then you can use a global catalog by specifying `GC://` in the LDAP path instead of `LDAP://`. The domains are in different forests, then you'll have to do one search per forest.